# How do we fix [Attempting to update (as part of an upsert) parent field Account__c with new value XXXXXXXX, current value is XXXXXXX]?

Tags: data-loader, account

Whenever i was trying to upload records, I received the below error.

> Attempting to update (as part of an upsert) parent field Account__c with new value XXXXXXXX, current value is XXXXXXX

Can any one help me to understand and solve this error?

Comment: Object name that you are making an **Upsert**? Which field you used as external id?

Comment: @Mahmood object = Account_Address__c , and the external Id = SUJ_EBS_ID__c

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the help doc [here](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000073334&language=en_US):
Error: "INVALID_FIELD_FOR_INSERT_UPDATE:Attempting to update (as part of an upsert) parent field"

Knowledge Article Number: 000073334

> Description
>
> You may encounter a Salesforce customer getting an
>   "INVALID_FIELD_FOR_INSERT_UPDATE: Attempting to update (as part of an
>   upsert) parent field"  error when attempting to insert / update /
>   upsert records via the API using Dataloader, Informatica, Workbench,
>   Etc....
>
> This error occurs because the customer has mapped values to a parent
>   field, which is not allowed.
>
> Resolution
>
> Please check the mapping file for the API tool, such as the dataloader
>   sdl or the Informatica mapping file. If the customer is attempting to
>   update another object through the relationship field, this may be the
>   problem. The resolution for this problem will be to try and update the
>   parent object in a separate job.
>
> Example:
>
> Contact.firstname =Ok!
>
> Contact.Accountid = Ok!
>
> Contact.Account.AccountName = BAD!
>
> Another example: Customer is trying to upsert Agreement__c object and
>   receiving the error "INVALID_FIELD_FOR_INSERT_UPDATE:Attempting to
>   update (as part of an upsert) parent field Customer__c with new value
>   001V000000ALga6IAD, current value is 001V000000AP1wkIAD:Customer__c
>   --".
>
> Resolution: Agreement__c has a master-detail relationship with
>   Account. As part of the upsert Customer__c field was getting updated
>   which is an ID field on Account object. Removing this ID field during
>   upsert was the resolution.